# Add colours to output of existing CLI commands

Tags: terminal, command-line, bash, zsh

I would like to create a function / alias that colorizes the output of another command. Is there a best-practice way to do so?

For instance, let's take the `alias` command, whose output looks something like this:

[image: Original]

In the standard bash/zsh, this is all in the same colour. However, I'd like to adjust the output so that the part before the alias itself (the part before the `=`) is green, and the aliased command (the part after `=`) is red, for instance.

Obviously, `alias` is just an example, as I would like to add colours to other commands.

My **current solution** uses `awk`:

```bsh
alias | awk -F"=" '{print "\033[1;32m" $1 "\033[0m=\033[1;31m"$2"\033[0m "}'
```

[image: MWE]

I don't find it particularly appealing (especially the colour codes). It also appears that this approach will become much more complicated for more complex commands (e.g. add colour output to `top` or `ps`) and also does not seem very maintainable in the long run.

Any ideas on how to make this better / easier ?

PS: I guess this is a Unix/Linux terminal question in general, but since I work primarily on OS X, I decided to start asking here...

---

**EDIT**: I now found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6540890/2269868) answer, that proposes using functions to make `awk` output look prettier. I'm not sure though if I want to have lots of formatting functions ghosting around my terminal. Still hoping for something cleaner...

Here's their example:

```
function red(s) {
    printf "\033[1;31m" s "\033[0m "
}

function green(s) {
    printf "\033[1;32m" s "\033[0m "
}

{
    print red($1), green($2), blue($3)
}
```

Comment: You could put the escape sequences used to switch colors into environment variables so you don't have to remember them each time (and to make it more easier to read)

Comment: I found a similar solution that uses bash functions, rather than env vars (see my edit above). Either way, these solutions would "pollute" my terminal & environment with unnecessary things that I never use directly.

Comment: Having things you never use directly is the whole idea behind abstractions. Not sure what you mean in term of "cleaner".

Comment: Also, you can't call bash functions from `awk` :-)

Comment: IMHO, you're going to have a much more difficult time trying to colorize the output of commands that weren't colorized from the get go.  If it's for a  single command or task you use repeatedly, I can see the benefit.  But for random commands, I think it would be more of a hindrance.

Comment: @Allan  I agree in general. My intention was to add colour to the commands that I use frequently to make my life easier. (such as e.g. setting/changing aliases on all my (many) work machines). I also agree on having a difficult time colourising the output, hence this question in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Especially since you're already using `zsh`, I would recommend using the existing highlighter framework (and builtin highlighters) of [`zsh-syntax-highlighting`](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-syntax-highlighting/blob/master/docs/highlighters.md) or [`fast-syntax-highlighting`](https://github.com/zdharma/fast-syntax-highlighting) Based on a preliminary review, both should have sufficient documentation to hopefully allow you to set up your preferred environment.

Here's a screenshot of `zsh-syntax-highlighting`'s default parser operating on the parsing command you provided (meta, right?)

[image]

Comment: It seems like this only handles input not the output of a command, right?

Comment: @stklik As written, correct, but my suggestion was that you use their parsing structure/code on the output with your own modifications/to set up your own environment.